# How can I integrate a value that I receive from a node?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm new to ROS and python so I do not know many things and recently I have a problem that I can not solve.

At one of my nodes, I receive a velocity vector [V, W], where W is the angular velocity and V the linear velocity of a unicycle robot. To get the model of this robot I need to integrate W and get Theta.

The question is how can I integrate the W value and get theta?
I have searched several integration topics but I can not do it. One method that I think can work is to use 'odeint' from the scipy library, however, I do not know how to use it, since the function receives (f, X0, t) a function, an initial condition, and a time vector. and since I do not have a function, only a value that reaches me every 0.01 seconds, I do not know how to use it.

I enclose my code in case someone can give me some guidance on this method or any other

```
import rospy
import numpy as np
from math import cos, sin
from prueba1.msg import TrayMensaje , VelMensaje #Mensajes propios
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from scipy.integrate import odeint


class Modelo():

def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('Modelo', anonymous=True)
        rospy.Subscriber('velLider', VelMensaje, self.callback)
        self.pub_modelo=rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
        self.vel_msg = VelMensaje()
        self.Mod_msg = Twist()      
        self.rate = rospy.Rate(10)

def callback(self,datos):
    self.vel_msg=datos
    
def f(y,t):
    return y

def robot(self):
    t0=-0.1
    t1=0
    theta0=0
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        V=self.vel_msg.V
        W=self.vel_msg.W
        t0+=0.1
        t1+=0.1
        t=[t0 , t1]
          #Integration of W = theta
        #[th , error]=odeint(self.f,theta0,t)
        #print th
        theta=0
        XLp=V*cos(theta)
        YLp=V*sin(theta)
        Thetap=W
        self.Mod_msg.linear.x=XLp
        self.Mod_msg.linear.y=YLp
        self.Mod_msg.linear.z=0
        self.Mod_msg.angular.x=0
        self.Mod_msg.angular.y=0
        self.Mod_msg.angular.z=Thetap
        self.pub_modelo.publish(self.Mod_msg)
        self.rate.sleep()
        
    rospy.spin()
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
     x= Modelo()
         x.robot()
  except rospy.ROSInterruptException: pass
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279996/how-can-i-integrate-a-value-that-i-receive-from-a-node?/) by [carlosal24](https://answers.ros.org/users/33317/carlosal24/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is actually not as hard as you're making it, but you probably want to take a step back and look at this from first principals.

Firstly the ODE integrator is intended to be used on a function so that the ODE function can choose to sample the function at different points in order to estimate the integral. This is not the case in your system because samples are only available when they're measured.

A more appropriate integration method would be the [Trapezoidal Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) which can work with an arbitrary set of samples. This is fairly simple to code from first principals because you're basically calculating the area of a rectangle and a right angle triangle each time step.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [carlosal24](https://answers.ros.org/users/33317/carlosal24/) on 2018-01-17**:
Thanks, it seems that with the trapezoid rule it works perfectly.